# External Logins with Facebook, Google etc

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver3, openid-connect

I am building an Authentication platform which also enables users to log in with External OAuth providers such as `Facebook`, `Google`, `Twitter`, `LinkedIn`, `Github`. I used `OpenID connect` to authenticate users through these providers. But my question is How does this work? To be more detailed:

1. User comes to my website and he tries to access some resources.
2. He will be redirected to a login page which has `username` and `password` along with options to log in from `Google`, `Facebook` etc.
3. User chooses to log in from `Google` then he is redirected to Google login page, There he enters username and password and accepts Consent.
4. He is redirected back to `redirect URI` I specified which is an API in my code.

**My Questions are:**

1. What I need to do in that API, do I have to create a user in my database at the first time? Do I have to create `user claims` returned from `Google` for that user?
2. I have seen a table called `UserLogins` in  Microsoft Identity. Is that table for External logins? This table has `UserId` column. So this table has the foreign key of Users Table.
3. Can a user have multiple external logins along with local login?
4. Any working sample on External logins with the persistent layer?